# Autolayout - view controller frame incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out why the frame of my view controller (loaded from a xib) is set properly when presented via presentViewController:

```
self.presentViewController(testVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

...but remains at (0, 0, 600, 600) when added as a child view controller:

```
self.addChildViewController(testVC)
self.view.addSubview(testVC.view)
testVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
testVC.view.setNeedsLayout(); (makes no difference)
```

I have an isolated example that I can provide that demonstrates the issue more clearly. Ideas?

Comment: Please present all code so can be reproduced?

Comment: A clear question with a clear answer, yet multiple downvotes. I'll never understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you forgot to give it a frame! You are saying:

```
self.view.addSubview(testVC.view)
```

But you neither apply a `frame` nor attach any constraints, so the view is not resized. *You* are now the parent. Resizing the child view is up to *you*. If you don't, its size is the size it had in the storyboard — 600 by 600, just as you said. It doesn't get resized by magic. *You* have to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Try This.

```
self.addChildViewController(testVC)
testVC.view.frame=self.view.bounds//or set by CGRectMake()
testVC.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.view.addSubview(testVC.view)
testVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```